# How to persist shapes in python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, shapes

I have an excel form with shapes. If I change only the sheet contents to Python without changing this form and save it, all the shapes will disappear.
I'm using openpyxl.
How to persist excel shapes in python?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking how to encode an Excel file's shapes in openpyxl data, and your goal is to have that data persist when you change the openpyxl data back into an Excel file format.

openpyxl is centered on transferability of data, data visualizations (e.g. charts), and some visual formatting information between Excel and python. But there is an [`openpyxl.chart.shapes`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.chart.shapes.html) submodule that may provide what you need.

Comment: Yes, but what I want is that when there is an image called a in the existing Excel file, when the file is modified and saved, a is still there.

Comment: i find doc, and i know openpyxl is not read every data in xlsx file(ex:shape), but i need that. i know roughly the ooxml format, but i don't know how can i put that shape, image things in xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need "xlwings".
xlwing does a lot of things that openpyxl doesn't work. Keep the shapes you want or keep the formulas... However, be careful as it cannot operate in an environment without Excel.

```
import xlwings

app = xlwings.App(visible=False)
wb=app.books.open('test.xlsx')
ws= wbxl.sheets[0]
ws.shapes
```

[xlwings docs](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Sheet.shapes)